# Unquoting from a Racket macro

Tags: macros, racket, quote

I have a function that does some processing on an expression:

```
(struct sym (s) #:transparent)

(define (foo-fn ex)
  (match ex
    [(? symbol? s) `(sym (quote ,s))]
    [(? list? xs) (cons (car xs) (map foo-fn (cdr xs)))]
    [x x]))
```

This function works as expected:

```
> (foo-fn '(cons x y))
'(cons (sym 'x) (sym 'y))
```

Now I am trying to make a macro that takes the expression it's given and replaces it with the result of `foo-fn`. I have managed to get some of the ways there with

```
(define-syntax-rule (foo ex)
  (foo-fn (quote ex)))
```

However, this macro still gives the quoted expression, and I would like the expression itself. That is, while my current code gives

```
> (foo (cons x y))
'(cons (sym 'x) (sym 'y))
```

I would prefer the result be

```
> (foo (cons x y))
(cons (sym 'x) (sym 'y))
```

I have managed to find a workaround through using `eval`, but I'm pretty sure this is not how macros are meant to be used (correct me if I'm wrong)

```
(define-syntax-rule (foo ex)
  (eval (foo-fn (quote ex))))
```

While the above works, it is my belief that it is an incorrect way to use macros. What is the preferred approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The root issue here is not in your `foo` macro, but in `foo-fn`. The `foo-fn` operates on datums, not syntax objects, so it throws away all lexical context and source location information. This is an irreversible operation, so there’s no way to “go back” from a quoted expression to pieces of syntax.

Instead of using `foo-fn` to perform your source transformations, it looks like you probably want the `foo` macro to do the syntax parsing itself. Using [`syntax/parse/define`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/syntax/Defining_Simple_Macros.html), this is quite straightforward:

```
(require syntax/parse/define)

(struct sym (s) #:transparent)

(define-syntax-parser foo
  [(_ s:id) #'(sym 's)]
  [(_ (f x ...)) #'(f (foo x) ...)]
  [(_ x) #'x])
```

By implementing this as a macro, you have a syntax-to-syntax transformation instead of a datum-to-datum one, which properly preserves lexical context. (This preservation is integral to the concept known as “macro hygiene”.)

Now, you can use the `foo` macro and get the result you expect:

```
> (foo (cons x y))
(cons (sym 'x) (sym 'y))
```